# Installing Kubuntu 22.04 on HP Pavilion

Tags: system-installation, hp-pavilion

I'm trying to install Kubuntu 22.04 on an HP Pavilion desktop using a USB stick.  I've disabled Secure Boot in the BIOS. I get to the boot prompt with no trouble. I select "Try or install Kubuntu".  There is some USB activity and then I get a screen with the HP logo and "kubuntu" flashing slowly. And there it sits for at least a hour, at which point I gave up.  The  USB stick is still lit up, indicating that it's active.

How can I get my Kubuntu going?

Update 1:The HP BIOS settings include settings for something called the TPM (Trusted Platform Module). Could that be involved somehow?  If so, what should I do about it?

Update 2: I've actually managed to install Kubuntu, but I can't get it started because **grub-install** fails.   I've created (and formatted) a FAT32 partition for EFI, but **grub-install** can't find it.

update 3: I now have a running Kubuntu system, but I can only get to it through a couple of levels of boot menus.  When I power up, I just get the grub prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The magic incantation is **acpi=off**.After the "Try Kubuntu" prompt,type **e**. Then edit the text to insert **acpi=off** after **quiet**, then get the installation going with F10.

This is necessary but not sufficient.